# Fetch unknown no. of fields in SQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

i have this successful query **coded inside PHP code**, the reason why I put a for loop inside the select query is that ncropfarmingreasonid is dynamic in the sense that future reason name and id will be added so that's why i have to loop the id inside the select statement base on how many rows in the table cropfarmingreason

**table cropfarmingreason**
[image: tbl_cropfarmingreason]

**table tbl_climatechange**
[image]
SQL:

```
              // to get the number of rows in table cropfarmingreason
  $sql = "SELECT * from tbl_cropfarmingreason order by ncropfarmingreasonid";    
                $query = pg_query($sql);
                $count_row = pg_num_rows($query);
              


 $qry_6_12 .= "  SELECT count(ncropfarmingreasonid) as counted , " ;
                            
         for($i=2;$i<=$count_row;$i++) // loop the number of rows and used $i as ncropfarmingreasonid 
              {           
                if(($count_row-$i)==0)
                  {
                     $qry_6_12 .= "SUM(CASE WHEN ncropfarmingreasonid = ".$i." THEN 1
                     ELSE 0 END) a".$i."";
                  }  
                else 
                  {
                     $qry_6_12 .= "SUM(CASE WHEN ncropfarmingreasonid = ".$i." THEN 1  
                     ELSE 0 END) a".$i.",";                                  
                  }        
              }
 $qry_6_12 .= " FROM tbl_climatechange as c, tbl_household as h, tbl_barangay as b where h.chholdnumber=c.chholdnumber and b.cbrgycode=h.cbrgycode and b.cbrgyname = 'AMPAYON' ";
 $query_6_12 = pg_query($qry_6_12);
```

and this is the result of the query :

[image: result]

I want to know if how can i fetch and assign the value in a variable of every field whithout knowing the no. of fields to be returned since table cropfarmingreason is dynamic. Hope someone could help me :) thanks

Comment: The answer is "no", unless you use dynamic SQL.  Nevertheless, you should correctly tag the question.  Which database are you using?

Comment: i used 1.16.0 version of postgresql

Comment: oh im sorry i used version 9.2

Comment: so whats your point sir ?

Comment: @daR, It should be possible to write some php functions that would write out the queries that you reqiure, as a string containing the SQL. These generated queries will then be executed. I deleted my original comment as it wasn't clear enough. If no one answers it then i will create a simple example later today.

Comment: It would help make the generated queries clearer, if you add an extra column to the 'table cropfarmingreason' that has one word describing the item. This  could be used as a 'column alias' in the 'generated query' of tbl_climatechange to make them easier to read.

Comment: @daR, please mark this problem as solved. Also, we would like to know what the answer was that you actually used, so please post what you actually used as an answer. You can answer your own questions. The idea is to spread knowledge here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used below query to get all values in unknown no. of fields return

SQL :

```
               while ($row_column = pg_fetch_array($query_6_12 )){
                 $col = array();
                    foreach ($row_column as $key=>$value){
                    $col[$key]=$value;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP could use some cleaning up too:

```
$qry_6_12 .= "  SELECT count(ncropfarmingreasonid) as counted" ; -- no comma here

for($i=2;$i<=$count_row;$i++) // loop the number of rows and used $i as ncropfarmingreasonid 
    {   -- comma goes before every added clause so it works with 0 additions too
        $qry_6_12 .= ", SUM(CASE WHEN ncropfarmingreasonid = ".$i." THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) a".$i."";
    }
```

But you still have a very ugly way of querying your database.